# Is there a way to upgrade ubuntu kernel, not the mainline kernel?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, 22.04

I have 22.04 LTS, but there is a compatibility issue with my running kernel,

which is `Ubuntu 5.19.0-35.36~22.04.1-generic 5.19.17`.

I know that I can install mainline kernels using the mainline package,
but I read that installing mainline kernels might have driver issues.
So if possible, I'd like to install the Ubuntu-modified kernel, which will be
something like `Ubuntu 5.15.0-58.64`. I searched for a way and the only way to upgrade Ubuntu kernels seems to be upgrading to the mainline one; is the above not possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking, and you didn't specify what Ubuntu 22.04 product (Server? Desktop? flavor?).  The 5.19 kernel is the HWE kernel; where as 5.15 is the GA kernel stack (*which is supported the life of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS & default if certain media/products are used - you didn't specify*).  Are you asking how to switch to the GA kernel stack (ie. remain on 5.15 for the life of 22.04?)  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I was just trying to downgrade the kernel because the 5.19.0-35 had compatibility issues with my device. I took care of it by building a patched kernel, guides from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

Comment: Personally I'd opt to use a *supported* kernel where all security patching etc. is taken care of by the Ubuntu Kernel Team (*with advice from Ubuntu Security built in*)...   If it's related to one kernel (eg. 5.19); switching stack to the GA (5.15) maybe an easy solution instead of you needing to apply/backport all security fixes/patches into the future, rebuild etc for as long as you use your product (esp. if machine is online). Ubuntu LTS products offer kernel stack choices; selected by installation ISO, but that can be changed post-install anytime (*more than one stack can co-exist too*)

Comment: This is a Q&A site (*Question and Answer site*) where comments are directed to the *Original Poster* as queries..  Responses should be given in your question (*once a comment is addressed in the question, it'll be removed*). This is not a forum!  If you want to take on the security/maintenance burden yourself that's your choice, but do consider using a *supported* kernel stack where all security is managed for you, unless you're fully aware of what you're taking on.  Your last comment appears to be question detail (*not a comment!*)